# Shorten Python imports?

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project. Let's call it `myproject`. Now my code is littered with `myproject.folder.file.function`. Is there anyway I can remove the need to prefix all my imports and such with `myproject.`? What if I want to rename my project later? It kind of annoys me that I need to prefix stuff like that when the very file I'm importing it from is inside that same project. Shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: "littered"?  Are you saying that being specific is bad?  Why are you claiming this is bad?  The "rename the project" use case is very rare (It's hardly any work.  I've done it and it only takes a few minutes to locate every instance of the name and fix them.)  What's the real problem with being explicit and clear?

Comment: All the files which include stuff from `myproject.` are *inside* `myproject.`. I don't think being explicit adds any more clarity; if anything it detracts from the clarity because it's more to read and comprehend. I was trying to refer to a function within the very same file, in fact immediately below where I was writing this "import" (url pattern), but I still had to write out the full path just to refer to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`from myproject.folder import file` (horrible name, btw, trampling over the builtin type `file`, but that's another rant;-), then use `file.function` -- if `file` (gotta **hate** that module name;-) is still too long for you, add e.g. `as fi` to the `from` statement, and use `fi.function`.  If you want to rename myproject to myhorror, you only need to touch the `from` statements addressing it (you could use relative imports, but those would break 2.5 compatibility and therefore ban you from App Engine for now -- too high a price to pay for minor convenience, for me at least;-).

**Edit**: if just about every file needs some given supporting module, that's a powerful reason for making sure that supporting module lives in a directory (or zipfile) that's on sys.path (it's probably worth doing even if, say, only 30% of the files need that supporting module!-).

Comment: +1 for `myproject` to `myhorror`, but I think the OP was just saying `myproject.folder_in_myproject.specific_file_in_my_project.function_I_want` rather than actually having a `file.py` file he/she was importing.

Comment: Chris is right. I don't have any files named `file.py`. I know about the `from` style imports, but this isn't a project-wide solution. I still have to have `myproject` at the top of every single file. And I don't know if this will work in Django urlpatterns? It's not really an import statement you just write it as a string, and then django dynamically imports it later.

Comment: @Mark, if "every single file" needs some supporting module, that's a **powerful** reason for making sure that supporting module lives in a directory (or zipfile) that's on `sys.path` (I'd surely do that even if it was "just" 30% or so of files -- for **every** file, I'd jump through rings of fire to do it!!!-).

Comment: @Alex: Write that as an answer and I'll give you the checkmark. That's the solution I was looking for but was too stupid to realize it :p

Comment: @Mark, edited this answer to include the consideration in the above comment, as per your suggestion!

Comment: Putting something like this in `settings.py` works nicely: `sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))`

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind clobbering file:

```
from myproject.folder import file
```

If you want to make file something shorter:

```
import myproject.folder.file as f
```

You could create your own import statement if you were feeling really fancy:

```
head = 'myproject.folder.'
def my_import(name,*args,**kwargs):
   try:
       return __import__(name, *args, **kwargs)
   except ImportError: 
       return __import__(head+name, *args, **kwargs)

file = my_import('file')
```

You can also be outright evil, and hack the builtin python import statement:

```
head = 'myproject.folder.'

_import = __import__ # don't clobber __import__ yet

def my_import(name,*args,**kwargs):
   try: 
       return _import(name,*args,**kwargs)
   except ImportError:
       return _import(head+name, *args, **kwargs)

__builtins__.__import__ = my_import # God just killed a maintainer

# elsewhere, after the above abomination has run:
import file # I hope you are happy.
```

Actually, I'm exaggerating the evil of clobbering built-in functions. It's not that bad. But it is a little bit hairy.

Comment: It actually *does* sound incredibly evil. +1 for effort, but I would never take this approach.

Answer (score 4):

```
import x as y
import x.y as z
from x import y as z
```

The "as" allows you to give your own name to an imported module. For example, `import os as System` would allow you to call the components of the `os` module like so:

`System.path.abspath('bla')`

For more information about imports, read: [Importing Python Modules](http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm)