# Python is not looking at current directory for imports, which is causing issues for generated protobuf files

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

In my project, no matter where I am or where the file I'm trying to import from is in, I have to specify the path, which is fine.

Ex: `import protos.example as example`, even when I'm already in the protos directory. So when the generated files are made, they naturally just say `import example_pb2 as example__pb2`, but with the way it is forcing me to put the full path, that natural way of generating doesn't work because it has to be `import protos.generated.example_pb2`.

How can I change this to where it automatically searches the current directory before needing to specify the location?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shorten Python imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760963/shorten-python-imports)

Comment: @Justlearnedit I don't believe so. The issue comes in generated files, where I think this would only help in self made files

Comment: You should put the protos.generated directory to your python path. There are several ways to do that (e.g. by setting the environment variable PYTHONPATH or adding it to the Python variable `sys.path`).

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix. I'm using Pycharm , not sure how this works in other IDEs. Right click the folder that has the generated files and mark it as sources. That solves the generated files not being able to see each other. Then in any file where you reference the generated files, put

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'generated')
```

and then your imports should work as expected